# how do I manage facebook access token?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, facebook

I have an app which user can login using twitter and facebook to login, had no issues with twitter as the access token never expires, however facebook does. In my app I can connect fb account if user login twitter and vice versa. Facebook is basically used to share something to user's wall. The issue that I am having now is that when a user tries to share something using their facebook account and the access token expires it pops up a login screen and after I login it doesn't share it anymore. So what is the best way to maintain this token? I've never had any experience using any other app that asks me to login again... how do they manage with this tok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to ask the permission "offline_access", this makes your access token last until the user decides to remove your application. In which case, you can decide to remove from your database his data or not via the deauthorization URL.

Answer (score 0):

See you need to understand that Facebook and Twitter works differently.

You can essentially store the accesstoken in NSUserDefaults as:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.accessToken forKey:@"fb_access_token"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"fb_exp_date"];
```

(I suppose you are already doing that)

the token lasts until date expiration, user changes account password, or user removes your application. in which case you will get an exception.
after getting an exception, you have to log in again and get the new token,and if you want to post the message again, the dialog-box will appear.
and since the FBDialog is a WebView, you cant perform the action without tapping on publish.